# Why are my Bitcoin/Bitcoin Cash commands not working on SV?

Tags: bitcoin-sv

Just trying to run some pretty simple commands on an SV node. Why am I getting this?

```
ey@BitcoinSV:~$ bitcoind -testnet
bitcoind: command not found
```

Comment: Hi cryptskip, your edit changed your post into a different question and made Andrew's answer not make sense anymore, so I reverted it.  It would be better if you'd ask your updated question as a new post.

Answer (score 4):

That error means that the command `bitcoind` was not found on your computer's path. Make sure that you have installed the software correctly such that the `bitcoind` binary is on the path.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin SV is a fork of bitcoin-core, so all the commands of bitcoin are almost the same as on Bitcoin SV

in here you can find all the RPC commands with much more details

https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#rpc-quick-reference